Are there any specific limits to the use of copyright law to restrict discussing contracts?
There is a case, reported on youtube where a  "bar certified" content creator showed for 54 seconds the "certified licence" that one receives from Splice, a company that provides licences to creators who reuse media, as well as their terms of service and the cease and desist letters they sent.  These were the subject of a DMCA takedown request to youtube, claiming copyright infringement by these sections of the video.
There are fair use questions that would be similar if this was some form of art work/creative media involving the standard four factors, but are there any rules specific to legal contracts that allow sharing and discussion of the contents?
On example where copyright law could be (ab)used by companies would be to only provide a paper version of the contact, and prohibit making a digital copy (similar to if one buys a physical book).  This would mean getting legal advice about the contract would require the time and expense of physically moving the contract.
Another possible way would be to only provide the contract online behind some form of DRM that prevents copying (similar to On Demand Video Services like Netflix).  This would leave the individual with no version to check what was agreed.

france
Are contracts protected by copyright?
Probably, but I am unsure.
The relevant statutes are articles L112-1 and L112-2 of the code of intellectual property:

(L112-1) Les dispositions du présent code protègent les droits des auteurs sur toutes les oeuvres de l'esprit, quels qu'en soient le genre, la forme d'expression, le mérite ou la destination.
(L112-2) Sont considérés notamment comme oeuvres de l'esprit au sens du présent code :
(snip...)


(L112-1) The present code protects author rights [= copyright and moral rights] on all works of mind, whatever the genre, expressive form, merit or object.
(L112-2) For the purpose of the present code, in particular, the following are works of mind:
[a whole bunch of categories, none of which really fits legal contracts]

Contracts and other legal documents do not fit in any of the categories enumerated at L112-2, but L112-2 is not an exhaustive list of all copyrightable works. Therefore the question becomes whether L112-1 still applies, i.e. whether a contract is a "work of mind".
I am inclined to say yes. After all, you are paying lawyers big bucks to draft them. Contracts are also original (the existence of badly-drafted contracts proves that well-drafted contracts are not the only way to write them).
Needless to say, searching for court cases on this exact point is difficult since "copyright contract" or similar search terms yield a lot of false positives.
Exceptions to copyright
Let us turn now to article L122-5:

Lorsque l'oeuvre a été divulguée, l'auteur ne peut interdire :
(...)
2° Les copies ou reproductions réalisées à partir d'une source licite et strictement réservées à l'usage privé du copiste et non destinées à une utilisation collective (...);
3° Sous réserve que soient indiqués clairement le nom de l'auteur et la source :
a) Les analyses et courtes citations justifiées par le caractère critique, polémique, pédagogique, scientifique ou d'information de l'oeuvre à laquelle elles sont incorporées ;
(...)
Les exceptions énumérées par le présent article ne peuvent porter atteinte à l'exploitation normale de l'oeuvre ni causer un préjudice injustifié aux intérêts légitimes de l'auteur.


Once the work has been published, the author cannot forbid:
(...)
2° Copies made from a licit source, for the private use of the copying person and not destined to collective use (...)
3° Under condition that the name of author and source are clearly indicated:
a) Analysis and short citations justified by a critical, polemic, pedagogic, scientific or informative purpose of the work into which they are included;
(...)
The aforementioned exceptions must not prevent the normal use of the work’s copyright nor cause an unjustified prejudice to the author’s legitimate interests.

Therefore

[One] example where copyright law could be (ab)used by companies would be to only provide a paper version of the contact, and prohibit making a digital copy (similar to if one buys a physical book). This would mean getting legal advice about the contract would require the time and expense of physically moving the contract.

Nope; you can make copies for private use, such as obtaining legal advice from your lawyer.
Imagine the following fact pattern: MovieStudio releases Slow and Calm, a contemplative movie about a retired taxi driver; one year later FilmLtd releases Sluggish and Sloppy; MovieStudio sues FilmLtd, arguing that the new movie is so similar to theirs (in scenario, visuals, etc.) as to constitute copyright infringement. FilmLtd’s lawyer will surely need a copy of Slow and Calm to mount an effective defense; if FilmLtd obtained such a file legally, they may share it with their lawyer.

A (...) content creator showed for 54 seconds the "certified licence" that one receives from Splice, a company that provides licences to creators who reuse media, as well as their terms of service and the cease and desist letters they sent.

I have not inquired about the facts beyond what was asked in the question, but the "content creator" may not have satisfied the "analysis and short citations" criterion here. They may legitimately discuss the legal documents (license, cease and desist letters, etc.) and quote portions of it; they might even have a case that waving the document around is legitimate as a way of showing they are not making stuff up about its length. However, having the full document onscreen in a way that allows easy reading might be unjustified. This would be a heavily fact-dependent analysis.
Note that Youtube DMCA mechanisms are optimized for speed and lower risk of suit. Keeping a video of unclear status online opens them up to litigation, even if they might eventually prevail, and in the aggregate they will lose a portion of unclear legal cases. Removing the video does not, because the video uploader signed the terms and conditions that will have "we can remove anything we want" somewhere. Therefore they are inclined to obey even the most dubious DMCA requests, as has been well-documented (example). (They work under US legislation, but EU legal incentives are much the same.)

Copying a contract for the purposes of executing or enforcing it is fair use
It self evidently meets the four-factor test.
copying for obtaining legal advice is one of the fair dealing exemptions

It seems this answer is specific to Australia?  This would not prevent DRM measures being used?
